# Object reference not set to an instance of an object label

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am new to asp. I get the below error, while transferring selected rows into data table.  I want all the rows as labels.

```
string EmployeeID = (row.Cells[3].FindControl("M_ID")).ToString();
```

and stack trace,

> [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.]    _Default.vilemail_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in
>   d:\Vinoth\Msmtest\vessel_inti.aspx.cs:79
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +111
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument) +110
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument) +10
>   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler
>   sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
>   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData)
>   +36    System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +1565

I know this is not much difficult, but I can't solve.

Comment: either `row`, `Cells[3]` or `FindControl("M_ID")` will be `null`. Debug your code and you should be able to spot it.

Comment: Adding that one to my favourites for when this gets asked for the 1,000th time.

Comment: how many columns are there in your datatable and what is M_ID

Comment: try find in row instead of concrete cell, like `row.FindControl("M_ID")`

Answer (score 0):

This will prevent exeception:

```
string EmployeeID = row.Cells[3].FindControl("M_ID") != null ? (row.Cells[3].FindControl("M_ID")).ToString() : string.Empty;
```

But you have to check in which condition `row.Cells[3].FindControl("M_ID")` getting null value.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by your question, this may what you need. Assuming that **M_ID** is a label id,

```
string EmployeeID = (row.Cells[3].FindControl("M_ID") as Label).Text;
```

You must specify what type of control you want to fetch from the page. In your case, it is a label, followed by the attribute of the control.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to get the `Id` of an Employee. In this case I prefer make this `Id` key of the row:

```
<asp:GridView ID="EmployeesGridView" runat="server" DataKeyNames="EmployeeID">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="EmployeeID" HeaderText="Employee" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

In this case when `SelectedIndexChanged` event fire you can get that key like this:

```
string EmployeeID = EmployeesGridView.SelectedDataKey.Value.ToString();
```

**Edit**
In case you already have a `DataKeyName` or you need more than one value from there just add all properties you need in the `DataKeyNames` in the grid like this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="EmployeesGridView" runat="server" DataKeyNames="EmployeeID,ID">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="EmployeeID" HeaderText="Employee" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="Id" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

And you can get them like this:

```
string EmployeeID = EmployeesGridView.SelectedDataKey.Value.ToString();
string id = EmployeesGridView..SelectedDataKey.Values["ID"].ToString();
```

Just remember that you need to think those values are primary keys of your grid so you can't have more than one row with same values/pairs.